# Image Size / Resolution for printing a Rollup

Tags: adobe-photoshop, file-size

I need to create a design for a rollup that will be 2000mm X 850mm. 
The place we're printing at has an info sheet, which only says the file should be 150dpi.  When trying to create a file to design this in, photoshop makes a 1GB file! 
Is there a trick that I'm missing here? I have never had to print anything this large...

Thanks!

Comment: 22GB? What the? I've made a Rollup at 200dpi and it had only 380MB...

Comment: Without seeing the artwork it's difficult to offer concise guidance

Comment: Alright, now that you've edited your question... 1GB does not strike me as a large file. It's not uncommon for me to work with Photoshop files that large (or bigger), especially if they are particularly image heavy

Comment: What's a rollup?

Comment: @DA01 Probably a pull-up banner or similar

Comment: There is a little mixed measurements here. The image dimensions are in milimeters but the resolution is in dots per inch. Doing the math, you end up with 11811 x 5020 pixel dimensions. Plain white background saved yields a 3MB file. Although 1GB file is not huge, I wonder if all the dimensions are entered correctly in setting up the file, or the image dimensions. I inserted an image and created 8 new layers of it to fill the entire space by sliding them around. The file size went up to 376MB, after flattening it the size went down to 163MB. Check your size, flatten the image.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help! I got the sizes mixed up and was confused between cm and mm, got it to work now with lower file size.

Answer (score 1):

1gb for a big file like this with the layers is not that bad although it is still big, but so is the file dimension.

You will send to the printer a flatten file, not a file with layers. I doubt your file will be that big once flatten (eg. all layers merged into 1 layer); depending on the file format you'll choose as  print-ready, it should be between +/- 50mb to 300mb.

If your issue is computer performance, then try using a publishing software like Indesign and use it to import your images and vectors separately. Add your texts in InDesign instead of Photoshop; create only the backgrounds and special effects in Photoshop. It's totally normal your PSD file is huge if you add many layers and all the texts as layers too.

If your computer can't take it, it's even possible you'll need to create different Photoshop files and add the merged layers into 1 file instead to not end up with too many layers!

I don't think you're missing anything, it's a big project! But maybe you could try Indesign and doing some elements in vectors if they can be done in vector.